# neo4j clearing whole relations index

Tags: neo4j

community. We have a strange behavior of neo4j database.
Few days ago we encountered a problem - whole relationships index were cleaned, can't find anything that lead to it.
Asking for your help
It is worked well in production for 2 years. Now if we restore from backup - it works for 2-3 hours and then cleaning relationships index (database losing 20gb of it's weight). This only occurs if we load it with requests.

Anyone encountered such problem?

Version:    4.2.0
Edition:    Enterprise

Comment: Pls report it to neo4j since it is serious matter.